# How to automatically install packages?

Tags: fedora, shell-script, package-management, yum

I want to install packages automatically by running a script

I can write `yum install php`, but I want it to install another package once installation of the php package is completed.

Is there any solution to make it automatic?

I have around 20 packages which are to be downloaded from remi repository.

Comment: Welcome to unix.se! In questions that require distribution-specific answers, please always include information about the distribution you are using. Judging from `yum`, I assume you are using Fedora.

Answer (score 4):

You can give more than one package name per call:

```
yum install php httpd this that andtheother win8
```

(but your repository probably won't have win8 `;)` )

Comment: but the issue would be , it will prompt for user input , I want it to install automatically . Is there any package management tool?

Comment: You can add '-y' which will assume 'yes' as input to all prompts.