# package management

Tags: package-management, packaging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [automatically installing packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46408/automatically-installing-packages)

I have two virtual machines, and I want to install packages atomically from repository . Is there any specific package management software, that install packages automatically,

Lets says that I have a fresh linux, and i want to install php 5.3 , mysql  , memcached , and I want them to be installed automatically by running a code or software. Is there any tool?

Answer (score 0):

There are many packages managers for linux.. What do you mean fresh linux? linux from scratch? If not than you probably already have installed package manager like Synaptic, Ubuntu software center, ...

Comment: Fresh linux, I mean a new linux machine. And I have to install 20packages, Normally I type in yum install php etc but I want a tool that I run it, and it automatically installs the packages which I list it in file or through console

Comment: You mean a single command like `yum install php5.3 mysql memcached`?

Comment: If you want `yum` to install packages which names are listed in a file or read from `STDIN` you can use `xargs`. If the packages are listed in a file the command looks like `cat file_with_package-names | xargs yum` or if you want to read the package names from `STDIN` which is very error-prone you must invoke `cat | xargs yum`